# Reference to a particular Prefab clone

Tags: unity

I am developing a simple 2D game. In game, I've created a prefab for charcaters. and I am changing sprite of prefab runtime. This all execute fine. 
Now I want to apply click event on a particular prefab clone and want to increase scale of prefab. I am attaching a c# script what I have did till now.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Shopping
{
    public string CharacterName;
    public Sprite CharacterSprite;
}

public GameObject CharacterPrefab;
public Transform CharacterSpacer;

public List<Shopping> ShoppingList;

private CharacterScript NewCharacterScript;

/*********************************************Awake()******************************************/
void Awake()
{
    MakeSingleton ();
}

/******************************Create object of the script**********************************/
void MakeSingleton()
{
    instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    LoadCharacters ();
}

void LoadCharacters()
{
    foreach (var characters in ShoppingList) {
        GameObject NewCharacter = Instantiate (CharacterPrefab) as GameObject;

        NewCharacterScript = NewCharacter.GetComponent<CharacterScript> ();
        NewCharacterScript.CharacterName = characters.CharacterName;
        NewCharacterScript.Charcater.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = characters.CharacterSprite;

        NewCharacterScript.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (() => CharacterClicked (NewCharacterScript.CharacterName, NewCharacterScript.Charcater));

        NewCharacter.transform.SetParent (CharacterSpacer, false);
    }
}

void CharacterClicked(string CharacterName, GameObject Char)
{
    StartCoroutine (IncreaseScale (Char));
}

IEnumerator IncreaseScale(GameObject TempCharacter)
{
    int i = 5;
    while (i > 0) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);

        Vector3 TempVector = TempCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale;
        TempVector.x = TempVector.x + 0.2f;
        TempVector.y = TempVector.y + 0.2f;
        TempCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale = TempVector;

        i--;
    }
}
```

This code triggers click event and also it increases scale but of last clone, not of clicked prefab clone.
What I am missing, I can't understand. What should I correct in this.
and Yeah! I am also attaching code of a script that I've added on prefab.

```
public class CharacterScript : MonoBehaviour {

public string CharacterName;
public GameObject Charcater;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved using OnMouseDown() method. Attach this script on the object oon which you want to trigger click event. Don't forget to add collider on that object.

```
public class MouseDownEffect : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private GameObject TempCharacter;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    StartCoroutine (IncreaseScale ());
}

IEnumerator IncreaseScale()
{
    int i = 5;
    while (i > 0) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);

        Vector3 TempVector = TempCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale;
        TempVector.x = TempVector.x + 0.2f;
        TempVector.y = TempVector.y + 0.2f;
        TempCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale = TempVector;

        i--;
    }
}
```

}